# dask-distributed: how to cancel tasks submitted with fire_and_forget?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

When submitting task graphs using fire_and_forget, is it possible to later (in a new process/client) cancel those tasks (e.g. by key name)?
And will that also cancel all dependent tasks, or are these also 'fire_and_forget'-like?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create a new future with the keyname

```
from dask.distributed import Future

future = Future(key_name, my_client)
future.cancel()
```

Forcing cancellation even in the face of multiple clients seems reasonable (`fire-and-forget` is considered its own client).  Implemented here: https://github.com/dask/distributed/pull/1408 .  In version > 1.18.3 you will be able to use the `force=True` keyword

```
future.cancel(force=True)
```

This will cancel the future, even if other clients desire it.

Comment: Thanks. How easy can it be... :-)
And how about the second part of my question? If I have submitted a long dsk using fire_and_forget, and I cancel the final task, will that also cancel the rest of the graph? Or do I need to cancel every single task separately?

Comment: Is is possible to design a long-running task that I can cancel once it has started executing?  I understand that it is difficult to kill a python thread, but can I instead message a task to shutdown cleanly using either metadata or signals?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49203128/how-do-i-stop-a-running-task-in-dask