# How do I stop a running task in Dask?

Tags: dask

When using Dask's distributed scheduler I have a task that is running on a remote worker that I want to stop.

How do I stop it?  I know about the `cancel()` method, but this doesn't seem to work if the task has already started executing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### If it's not yet running

If the task has not yet started running you can cancel it by cancelling the associated future

```
future = client.submit(func, *args)  # start task
future.cancel()                      # cancel task
```

If you are using dask collections then you can use the `client.cancel()` method

```
x = x.persist()   # start many tasks 
client.cancel(x)  # cancel all tasks
```

#### If it is running

However if your task has already started running on a thread within a worker then there is nothing that you can do to interrupt that thread. Unfortunately this is a limitation of Python.

#### Build in an explicit stopping condition

The best you can do is to build in some sort of stopping criterion into your function with your own custom logic. You might consider checking a shared variable within a loop. Look for "Variable" in these docs: http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/futures.html

```
from dask.distributed import Client, Variable

client = Client()
stop = Variable()
stop.set(False)

def long_running_task():
    while not stop.get():
        ... do stuff

future = client.submit(long_running_task)

... wait a while

stop.set(True)
```

Comment: What is the lifetime of a Variable?  If no clients have a reference to it, is it garbage collected?  Aside:  for long-running tasks, I instead set meta-data using the long-running-task's key so that "If the key corresponds to a task then that key will be cleaned up when the task is forgotten by the scheduler"

Comment: Yes, variables are cleaned up if no reference to them exists.

Comment: This seems to be old information. I am able to stop running tasks just by calling Future.cancel().

Comment: Well, I can confirm this happens. I am very surprised!

Comment: Can someone officially confirm whether it is possible to cancel an already-running task? From my test it seems not to be able to cancel a task - at least a dummy cpu-bound one... @MRocklin?

Comment: @SCGH, Can you share a minimal example showing this?

Comment: @MRocklin This solution assumes that the while loop will keep looping. What if there's a line of code inside the while loop that is hanging?