# Ignore long running tasks in Dask distributed

Tags: python, distributed, dask

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49203129/8025382) is discussed that already started tasks can not be canceled in Dask (language limitation).

But what if I just want to omit those tasks?

```
start_computing_time = time.time()

for future in task_pool:
    if condition:
       do_something_long(future.result()) 
    else:       
       future.cancel()

total_computing_time = time.time() - start_computing_time
```

In my application, execution time is critical. Once the stopping condition is met, I just want to omit running tasks, as I am no longer interested on those results. As to my knowledge, `future.cancel()` will just cancel not yet running futures.

But for those tasks in execution, is there any way to ignore them?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the [as_completed](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/futures.html#waiting-on-futures) iterator might solve your problem.  You can wait on a set of futures and update your system as they arrive.  Then you have enough information (or a timeout has passed) you would just move on and delete the running futures.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using the `as_completed` iterator (`task_poll = as_completed(futures)`); but as I understand it, running futures can not be canceled (and by the time the line `future.cancel()` is executed, the future is already computed)

Comment: Correct.  You can't stop running threads in Python.  However not all futures are actively running, some may be waiting for an open slot, or waiting on dependencies.